# Change arguments of a function using a MethodDecorator, without altering the "this value"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript-decorator

Imagine you have to **change method arguments** at runtime, using a decorator. A trivial example to make it simple: all arguments being set to "Hello World":

```js
export const SillyArguments = (): MethodDecorator => {
  return (
      target: Object,
      propertyKey: string | symbol,
      descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) => {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = (...args: any[]) => {
      Object.keys(args).forEach(i => {
        args[i] = 'Hello World';
      });

      return originalMethod.apply(null, args);
    };

    return descriptor;
  }
};
```

Example usage:

```js
class TestClass {
  private qux = 'qux';

  @SillyArguments()
  foo(val: any) {
    console.log(val);
    console.log(this.qux);
    this.bar();
  }

  bar() {
    console.log('bar');
  }
}

const test = new TestClass();
test.foo('Ciao mondo'); // prints "Hello World"
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'qux' of null

The problem here is `apply(null, args)`, which changes the context of `this`. This makes impossible to call the instance variable named `qux`, from inside `foo()`.

Another possibility is to change the call to `originalMethod.apply(target, args)`, but this time `qux` is `undefined`, while `bar()` can be invoked.

Is there any possibility to invoke the `originalMethod` with the context of `this` correctly set to the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `function` function instead of an arrow function so that you receive the original `this` context and can pass it along:

```
export const SillyArguments = (): MethodDecorator => {
  return (
      target: Object,
      propertyKey: string | symbol,
      descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) => {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
      Object.keys(args).forEach(i => {
        args[i] = 'Hello World';
      });

      return originalMethod.apply(this, args);
    };

    return descriptor;
  }
};
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks.